# Div positioning screwing with my head across browsers?

Tags: css, html, positioning

Please could a CSS expert tell me why my site looks ok on most browsers but when it comes to IE it screws up. there is nothing special in the CSS just positioning background and border settings..

It screws up on the white border at the right of the nav and the red border on the left of the main box.

Its perfect in FF and Safari and Chrome but IE its out by a few pixels..

How can i get it working across all ??

http://www.uniquegeeks.co.uk/djeurope/

Its almost as if IE puts the border on the inside and the rest put it border on the outside... the top and bottoms are curved imgs

[image]

Thanks

Lee

Comment: In IE8 it looks fine to me. Which version are you testing in?

Comment: Looks fine in IE9, are you maybe zooming things?

Comment: Try posting a screen shot of the issue.

Comment: its gone screwy on the corners of the red and white outlined box... can you see ?

Comment: @tw16 - added screenshot

Comment: I think that happens when you zoom in too much

Comment: @ibu no its like that as standard i just zoomed to show you guys...

Comment: Strange, I cannot replicate the issue in IE8. It looks fine to me, even when I zoom right in. Are you using real IE8 or a compatibility mode/emulator?

Comment: I can't repro either. You *must not* test it by zooming in using the browser. That's not a fair test. You have to take a screenshot, and zoom in on that.

Comment: trying it in bootcamp IE8 so pretty much full on IE8. i will change the picture to non zoomed

Comment: Just to prove that I *really can't* repro, here's an animation showing the difference between Firefox 5 and IE8 both captured at 100% browser zoom with a 500% nearest neighbour zoom in Photoshop to make it easier to see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YhnT7.gif

Comment: see now this is screwing me up even more - i have tried it on 2 totally different machines and it gives me the borders out on both machines.... wtf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its almost as if IE puts the border on the inside and the rest put it border on the outside

That's exactly what IE does (versions lower that 9 at least, not sure about 9).  I find the best approach to something like this is to supply an additional stylesheet using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can override the border settings for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="fix_ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: So IE is adding border to the outside ?? all other browsers are inside ?

Comment: Only less than IE 6, or IE6/7/8/9 in Quirks Mode use the broken box model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug. His page isn't in Quirks mode, and his borders are images.

Comment: @thirtydot: that was what I thought too, but that's the behaviour he's describing and yet his doctype looks correct.

Comment: This is why its screwing my head up... spent over an hour on this already :-(

Answer (score 2):

He is talking about IE 6 :)

For example for you png images use this http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/
just include the file and pass the selectors to it, it will make your png images transparent.

And i would recomend you useing a css reset.

before the body in the css add

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it :-(

Comment: in the comments he says he's talking about IE8.